# Why does my animation cut my message boxes?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, dialog

I  just wanted to know why it is that when I use the Frame Application and mix Dialog boxes and Animations, the text boxes are completely cut out.

Here is my code:

```
/* The "SpaceTravels" class.
   Date: March 2015
   Author Barrington Reid
   Description: This program asks user for identification,
   then will display a spaceship travelling through the night sky using Graphics.
   The spaceship is controlled by a slow setting, a medium setting and a fast setting.
*/
import javax.swing.*;           //Allows JOptionPane to work
import java.awt.*;

public class SpaceTravels extends JFrame
{
    ImageIcon backGnd, rckt;

    int x = 0;                //Setting the x variable as 0
    int y = 600;              //Setting the y variable as 600
    int xSpeed = 10;          //Setting the xSpeed as 10
    int ySpeed = 10;          //Setting the ySpeed as 10
    int number = 0;           //stores the verification number


    public SpaceTravels ()
    {
        super ("SpaceTravels");  // Set the frame's name
        setSize (1360, 730);     // Set the frame's size
        backGnd = new ImageIcon ("night.gif");    //Night background
        rckt = new ImageIcon ("orangerocket.png");       //Rocket
        setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       //Close the program by clicking exit
        setVisible (true);       // Show the frame
    } // Constructor


    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i = i + 1)
        {
            backGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            rckt.paintIcon (this, g, x, y);

            y = y + ySpeed;

            for (int j = 0 ; j < 1000000 ; j = j + 1)
            {
                double k = 1;
                Math.pow (k, 2);
            }
            if ((y > 600) || (y < 50))
            {
                ySpeed = ySpeed * -1;
            }


            for (int k = 0 ; k < 1000000 ; k = k + 1)
            {
                double l = 1;
                Math.pow (l, 2);
            }
            if ((x > 600 || (x < 50))
            {
                xSpeed = xSpeed * -1;
            }
        }
    } // paint method


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new SpaceTravels ();    // Create a SpaceTravels frame
        String name;            //Stores names
        int tries = 0;          //Stores the amount of tries
        String verCode = "1234567";                         //Verification Code is 1234567
        String code = "1234567";                            //Verification Code is 1234567

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Hello, and welcome to the Canadian Space Agency's Spacecraft Control and Simulation Program!"); //Welcome
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Your verification code is 1234567.");             //This is the verification code

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "For safety purposes, please enter your name");           //Asking for user name
        verCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Now, " + name + ", please enter your verification code."); //Enter the verification code: 1234567

        while ((verCode.equalsIgnoreCase ("1234567") != true) && (tries < 3))                      //3 tries to get this correct
        {
            verCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "You have entered the wrong verification code, please try again.");
            tries = tries + 1;          //Tries goes up once each time this loop occurs.
        }

        if (code.equals (verCode))
        {
            String[] options = new String[]  //This is a code that I found on (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257420/making-a-joptionpane-with-4-options)
            {
                "Slow", "Medium", "Fast"     //Speed options, slow, medium and fast
            }
            ;
            int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog (null, "What would you like the velocity of the rocket to be?", "Rocket speed",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options [0]);  //This is the name of the box, and what the box displays inside.
        }

        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Sorry, " + name + ", you have unsuccessfully identified your session. Please try again in 10 minutes.");
        }

    }


    // main method
} // SpaceTravels class
```

When I remove the graphics code, the message boxes work the way they should work.

Comment: You're overriding `paint` (of a top level container) but not calling `super.paint`, breaking the paint chain

Comment: I'm not a very adept programmer, as I have only started a few days ago. So I am not sure what super.paint means

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: You've overridden the method `paint`, which defined within the class hierarchy inherited from `JFrame`.  `paint` does a number of important jobs within this class hierarchy, but you've broken, by not call `super.paint(g)` first to ensure that it's functionality is executed before you perform your own.  Having said that, it's not recommended to override `paint` generally and even more so for top level containers like `JFrame`

Comment: What I might recommend is, you have a read through [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and gain a little more understanding of Object Oriented Programming before you try and tackle complex subjects like user interfaces, graphics and game design - IMHO

Comment: Okay, I will try doing that.

Answer (score 1):

- Overriding `paint` without calling `super.paint` first will break the functionality provided by the parent class and cause no end of issues with how the painting works.  Instead of extending from `JFrame` and overriding it's paint routines (which are complex enough), start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method (calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting).  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.
- Make sure you are running your UI from within the context of the event dispatching thread. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

For example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            String name;            //Stores names
            int tries = 0;          //Stores the amount of tries
            String verCode = "1234567";                         //Verification Code is 1234567
            String code = "1234567";                            //Verification Code is 1234567

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, and welcome to the Canadian Space Agency's Spacecraft Control and Simulation Program!"); //Welcome
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your verification code is 1234567.");             //This is the verification code

            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "For safety purposes, please enter your name");           //Asking for user name
            verCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Now, " + name + ", please enter your verification code."); //Enter the verification code: 1234567

            while ((verCode.equalsIgnoreCase("1234567") != true) && (tries < 3)) //3 tries to get this correct
            {
                verCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "You have entered the wrong verification code, please try again.");
                tries = tries + 1;          //Tries goes up once each time this loop occurs.
            }

            if (code.equals(verCode)) {
                String[] options = new String[] //This is a code that I found on (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257420/making-a-joptionpane-with-4-options)
                {
                    "Slow", "Medium", "Fast" //Speed options, slow, medium and fast
                };
                int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What would you like the velocity of the rocket to be?", "Rocket speed",
                                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                null, options, options[0]);  //This is the name of the box, and what the box displays inside.
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, " + name + ", you have unsuccessfully identified your session. Please try again in 10 minutes.");
            }
        }

        // Create main UI??
    });
}
```