# Swing, classes, and Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Now this probably sounds like a dumb question to you, but I'm new to all of this. So I'm writing a quiz app in java, and so far I only have 1 question in it. It isn't supposed to be a fully fledged app, it's just something I'm doing for a project.

So I have this class, which is the first question, completed design and all that. When the answer is submitted, it gets sent to the local database that I access from pMA. So far so good. The thing is though, a quiz is supposed to have more than one question. The problem is, I have no idea how to modify my gui, or class to do that. Ideally, I'd have the "Submit" button submit the answer to db and go to the next question, except I don't know how to add a question and have my gui present in in the same jpane instead of the first question. 
Do I make separate classes in the package for each of the questions and interconnect them somehow, or what?

I should note that I know only a little bit of java, so giving vague answers that are clear to most, will probably not be clear to me. Thank you for your patience.

All of this was done in the Netbeans gui builder, which means I can't edit most of the code, so ideally, I would just copy paste this and change values for other questions.

My code for the first question is here:

```
package quiz;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Statement st;
    String value;

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton4 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Koja je visina Mont Everesta?");

        jRadioButton1.setText("8848 metara");
        jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton2.setText("9848 metara");
        jRadioButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton3.setText("10848 metara");
        jRadioButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton4.setText("11848 metara");
        jRadioButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Dalje");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/quiz/mountain.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 294, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton4)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton1))
                        .addGap(124, 124, 124))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addContainerGap())))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(100, 100, 100))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jRadioButton4)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
//auto generated gui above
    private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        value="8848";
    }                                             

    private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        value="9848";
    }                                             

    private void jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        value="10848";
    }                                             

    private void jRadioButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        value="11848";
    }                                             

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
                String submitQuery="INSERT INTO uneseniodgovori(uo) VALUES (?)";
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javaquiz", "root", "");
                pst=con.prepareStatement(submitQuery);
                pst.setString(1, value);
                pst.executeUpdate();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Vas odgovor je postavljen uspjesno!");
                        String extractQuery="select uneseniodgovori.uo, odgovori.odg from odgovori inner join(select uo from uneseniodgovori order by id desc limit 1) as uneseniodgovori on uneseniodgovori.uo=odgovori.odg";
                        pst=con.prepareStatement(extractQuery);
                        rs=pst.executeQuery();
                        if(rs.next()){
                            String valueQuery="INSERT INTO uporedi(vrijednost) VALUES(?)";
                            pst=con.prepareStatement(valueQuery);
                            pst.setString(1, "Tacno!");
                            pst.executeUpdate();
                        }
                        else{
                            String valueQuery="INSERT INTO uporedi(vrijednost) VALUES (?)";
                            pst=con.prepareStatement(valueQuery);
                            pst.setString(1, "Netacno!");
                            pst.executeUpdate();
                        }
    }                                        
        catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
}





    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton4;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Here are some examples of using [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html): [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49519023/2180785), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637817/2180785), [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321214/2180785). It will help you change from one question to the other keeping the same layout and just changing the values inside.

Comment: You will also probably want to have a Question class with an array of `String`s for the answers and (maybe) an `int` for the correct answer for each question. Then just generate all the panes with all those information and switch them with the `CardLayout`