# Java ActionListener not working but no errors

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, cardlayout

So, I have been trying to learn how to work with `WindowBuilder` for the last month. I have watched a few YouTube videos especially about `CardLayout`, but my buttons don't seem to change the panels.

I'm actually aiming for a runnable game, but since I don't know where exactly to start, I have decided to code the part of the changing panel first.(sb told me my code wasn't exactly good for a game)

I want the panel to change when the player clicks on "New Game". It gave me errors at first, but after a few changes, it doesn't even give errors.
So here is my code:

```
package halma.views;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel returnBar_panel;
    private JPanel gameBar_panel;
    private JPanel startupReturnBar_Panel;
    private JPanel returnGame_Panel;
    private JPanel gameGUI_Panel;
    private JPanel startupGameBar_Panel;
    private JButton playButton;
    private JButton highScoresButton;
    private JButton exitButton;
    private JPanel resumeReturn_Panel;
    
    static ActionListeners action = new ActionListeners();

    
    CardLayout cardLayout1;  //Used for the buttons' actionlistener.
    CardLayout cardLayout2;
    
    
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
    }

    //The constructor method.
    public MainFrame() {
        createFrame();
        
        cardLayout1 = (CardLayout)(returnBar_panel.getLayout());
        cardLayout2 = (CardLayout)(gameBar_panel.getLayout());
    }
    
    
    
    //The getters and setters that are required for other classes to use the private variables in the "MainFrame" class.
    
    public JButton getPlayButton() {
        return playButton;
    }

    public JPanel getReturnBar_panel() {
        return returnBar_panel;
    }

    public void setReturnBar_panel(JPanel returnBar_panel) {
        this.returnBar_panel = returnBar_panel;
    }

    public JPanel getReturnGame_Panel() {
        return returnGame_Panel;
    }

    public void setReturnGame_Panel(JPanel returnGame_Panel) {
        this.returnGame_Panel = returnGame_Panel;
    }

    public JPanel getGameGUI_Panel() {
        return gameGUI_Panel;
    }

    public void setGameGUI_Panel(JPanel gameGUI_Panel) {
        this.gameGUI_Panel = gameGUI_Panel;
    }

    public void setPlayButton(JButton playButton) {
        this.playButton = playButton;
    }

    public JPanel getResumeReturn_Panel() {
        return resumeReturn_Panel;
    }

    public void setResumeReturn_Panel(JPanel resumeReturn_Panel) {
        this.resumeReturn_Panel = resumeReturn_Panel;
    }

    
    
    //Runs the game.
    public static void runGame() {
        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    
    
    //Creating the frame.
    
    public void createFrame() {
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 527, 374);
        setSize(800, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(255, 192, 203));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        returnBar_panel = new JPanel();
        returnBar_panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 192, 203));
        
        gameBar_panel = new JPanel();
        gameBar_panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 192, 203));
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(returnBar_panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 155, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(gameBar_panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 603, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(returnBar_panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 551, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(gameBar_panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 551, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        gameBar_panel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
        
        startupGameBar_Panel = new JPanel();
        
        startupGameBar_Panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 192, 203));
        gameBar_panel.add(startupGameBar_Panel, "name_328512842567600");
        
        playButton = new JButton("New Game");
        playButton.setFocusable(false);
        playButton.setBackground(new Color(255, 160, 122));
        playButton.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        playButton.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        playButton.addActionListener(action);
        
        
        highScoresButton = new JButton("Records");
        highScoresButton.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        highScoresButton.setFocusable(false);
        highScoresButton.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        highScoresButton.setBackground(new Color(255, 160, 122));
        
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        exitButton.setFocusable(false);
        exitButton.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        exitButton.setBackground(new Color(255, 160, 122));
        GroupLayout gl_startupGameBar_Panel = new GroupLayout(startupGameBar_Panel);
        gl_startupGameBar_Panel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_startupGameBar_Panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, gl_startupGameBar_Panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(490, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(gl_startupGameBar_Panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(exitButton, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(highScoresButton, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(playButton, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGap(24))
        );
        gl_startupGameBar_Panel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_startupGameBar_Panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, gl_startupGameBar_Panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(341, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(playButton)
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addComponent(highScoresButton)
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addComponent(exitButton)
                    .addGap(105))
        );
        startupGameBar_Panel.setLayout(gl_startupGameBar_Panel);
        
        gameGUI_Panel = new JPanel();
        gameGUI_Panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        gameBar_panel.add(gameGUI_Panel, "name_328347141657400");
        gameGUI_Panel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
        returnBar_panel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
        
        setStartupReturnBar_Panel(new JPanel());
        getStartupReturnBar_Panel().setBackground(new Color(255, 192, 203));
        returnBar_panel.add(getStartupReturnBar_Panel(), "name_328000881526100");
        
        returnGame_Panel = new JPanel();
        returnGame_Panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 192, 203));
        returnBar_panel.add(returnGame_Panel, "name_328006822278900");
        
        resumeReturn_Panel = new JPanel();
        resumeReturn_Panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        returnBar_panel.add(resumeReturn_Panel, "name_331156929215800");
        resumeReturn_Panel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }

    public JPanel getStartupReturnBar_Panel() {
        return startupReturnBar_Panel;
    }

    public void setStartupReturnBar_Panel(JPanel startupReturnBar_Panel) {
        this.startupReturnBar_Panel = startupReturnBar_Panel;
    }




package halma.views;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ActionListeners extends MainFrame implements ActionListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 814839576128286295L;
    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    
    public ActionListeners() {
        
        frame.runGame();
        
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("meow!");
        frame.cardLayout1.show(frame.getReturnBar_panel(), "resumeReturn_Panel");

        if(e.getSource() == frame.getPlayButton()) {
            System.out.println("T");
            frame.cardLayout1.show(frame.getReturnBar_panel(), "resumeReturn_Panel");
            frame.cardLayout2.show(frame.getGameGUI_Panel(), "Playing");
        }
    }
}
```

In the Second class, the word "Meow" gets printed, but the panel doesn't change even if I put it out of the `if-statement`. And the letter `T` doesn't get printed.

Comment: 1) Don't post the code as snippets (That's for JS code). 2) A single space between lines is all that is ever needed, multiple lines of them will make it harder for you and everyone else to read and follow the flow of the program. 3) Give your class a more meaningful name, `MainFrame`, I've seen countless of programs with the same name and I have to delete them from my current package to run the next one, a better idea would be `MeowMainFrame` or something like that. 4) There's no need to extend `JFrame` as you're not changing its behavior...

Comment: ... actually it's never a good idea to inherit from `JFrame`, see [extends JFrame vs creating it inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22003802/2180785), better to build your GUI based on `JPanel`s which are more flexible components than `JFrame`. And 5) For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue. `runGame()` doesn't appear in your code. 6) Why do you have 2 card layouts?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49519023/2180785) of the use of CardLayout. And [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637817/2180785) and [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54043710/2180785). Why not [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321214/2180785)? You choose, and you can see all of those are examples of the [mre] as you can copy-paste-compile-run without modifications and see the same output, that's what is expected from you if you want further help here

Comment: Frakcool I wanted to change both the left side and the right side when clicked on the button.That's why I added two CardLayouts.Now that I've seen people's reactions it doesn't not seem to be a good idea though.

Comment: Stop what you're doing and go through Oracle's tutorial on Swing.  You can skip the NetBeans section, but study the rest of the tutorial.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: Those 2 panes should be wrapped inside a single `JPanel` that you place into your `CardLayout`. But currently your code is really tangled. You have 3 different `JFrame`s in your program. The one you inherit from, you create a new instance in `MainFrame` and another one from `ActionListeners`, you shouldn't be exposing the `JPanel`s but the data inside them in the getters and setters.

Comment: I would avoid using a GUI to lay out your panels, buttons etc,  They generate obscure code which can be a nightmare to debug.  I would learn about layout managers, and other tools to lay out your components.  And also avoid absolute positioning of components. They don't lend themselves to scaling and if you need to add another component, you will have to adjust them.  Let the layout managers do their work.  It would, imo, be better to write you own layout manager if the current ones don't meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want an `ActionListener` to have a `Frame`? Wouldn't it it make more sense for a `Frame` to have an `ActionListener`? Even for a frame to have an action listener makes little sense. You want the component receiving the user action (the source object) to contain the listener. For example, if a user clicks on a button, you want that button to react to the **action** initiated by the user. For instance, if you have a button that should display "hello" in the console when clicked by the user, you would do something like this:

```
helloBtn.addActionListener(listener);
```

Then, your listener should look something like this:

```
public class HelloMsgListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

When your listener is this simple, it might make more sense to add it as an anonymous entity.

The code you wrote is very messy. You created a listener that has a frame, but that frame is not the instance that has the component that contains the listener with the frame.

The way to fix this is to create a class that creates the frame and runs your application

```
public class MyApp {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run () {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }

            private void createAndShowGUI () {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                ...
                frame.setVisible(true);
                // Create the rest of the components and add to frame
                playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("meow!");
                        frame.cardLayout1.show(frame.getReturnBar_panel(),
                            "resumeReturn_Panel");
                    
                        if (e.getSource() == frame.getPlayButton()) {
                            System.out.println("T");
                            frame.cardLayout1.show(frame.getReturnBar_panel(),
                                "resumeReturn_Panel");
                            frame.cardLayout2.show(frame.getGameGUI_Panel(), "Playing");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, you create your button

Comment: Thanks!It makes more sense now.